# How can I get data from laravel using stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, laravel

I want to get the data and put it on dd just try check and got nothing

Here is my controller

**controller.php**

```
public function editView($crewprogrammemoid){
    $transactionmemo = DB::connection('sqlsrv2')
    ->select("exec sp_Crewprogrammemo_Select 'crewprogrammemo_id = ''?'' ' ", [$crewprogrammemoid]);
    dd(collect($transactionmemo)->all()));
}
```

and I got nothing

[image]

How do I solve that? Because if I can, I try to get some specific column.

Here is the data when I execute on my SQL Server:

[image]

For example I want to try getting value on column like this

```
dd($transractionmemo['show_name']);
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Replace `''?''` with `?`

Comment: you mean change into this? ```$transactionmemo = DB::connection('sqlsrv2')->select("exec sp_Crewprogrammemo_Select 'crewprogrammemo_id = ? ' ", [$crewprogrammemoid]);``` , i tried that and i got this error ```SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '?'. (SQL: exec sp_Crewprogrammemo_Select 'crewprogrammemo_id = CP20020013 ' )```